# WordPress Menuing Question :focus

Tags: functions, css, html

I'm using the following script in the WordPress functions.php file to disable top level parent items when they have a submenu.  It works perfectly, but I need to it actually work like this:

If someone is using a mouse and clicks on the link - go ahead and load the parent link 
If someone is using a keyboard and tabbing through - if they enter on the parent link - don't load it

Right now, it's blocking the link on the both.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
function jqueryscript_in_head(){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j("li:has(ul)").children("a").click(function () {
return false;
});  });
</script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'jqueryscript_in_head');
```